# Why do transits of Earth across the Sun seen from Mars follow a pattern of occurring after 26, 79 then 100 years?

Tags: orbit, earth, mars, planetary-transits

According to [this answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/26178/7982) transits of Earth across the disk of the Sun as seen from Mars:

> The (Arthur C.) Clarke story is quite correct. Earth (and Moon) would transit the sun from the viewpoint of Mars on 8 May 1905, 11 May 1984 and again on 10 Nov 2084.

no surprises there, but they

> ...follow a pattern of occurring after 26, 79 then 100 years.

Why is that exactly? Why this pattern?

Comment: The Wikipedia addresses this, but not in much detail.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transit_of_Earth_from_Mars#Conjunctions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Such transit events occur when Earth and Mars are simultaneously at a node where their orbital planes intersect.

Between transits at the *same* node, both Earth and Mars must complete whole numbers of orbits, where 1 Mars year = 1.8808 Earth years.
[Meeus and Goffin 1983](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1983JBAA...93..120M/abstract) identify patterns of 79-year and 284-year intervals:

79.0 Earth years ≈ 42.0 Mars years

284.0 Earth years ≈ 151.0 Mars years

Their Table II arranges the May and November transit dates in separate "panoramas" with 284 years between rows and 79 years between columns.
These are somewhat analogous to a [saros-inex panorama](https://eclipse.gsfc.nasa.gov/SEsaros/SEperiodicity.html#section109) of solar eclipses.

Between transits at *opposite* nodes, both Earth and Mars must complete odd numbers of half-orbits:

Nov→May: 25.5 Earth years ≈ 13.56 Mars years

May→Nov: 100.5 Earth years ≈ 53.43 Mars years

These Mars year fractions differ from 0.5 because the half-orbit near perihelion takes significantly less time than the half near aphelion.
Meeus and Goffin Table I also shows some intervals of 21.5 and 53.5 years outside the present few centuries.

Comment: Very nice answer, thanks!