# Is there an online planetarium where the observer is on another celestial body?

Tags: software

I know about [in-the-sky.org](https://in-the-sky.org/) and its [online planetarium](https://in-the-sky.org/skymap.php) feature, but that's from the Earth's perspective. Is there a planetarium (preferably online but if not, that's fine) where the observer is on another celestial body, like the Moon or Mars?

Comment: just fyi [How will planets behave in the night sky as seen by Mars colonists?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/26166/7982) currently has no accepted answer

Comment: There's also [SpaceEngine application](http://spaceengine.org/). It is free. Sadly it's not available on Linux and Mac systems, but it works with Wine.

Comment: I can't remember where, thus the comment-not-answer but I have seen one. Earthrise on the moon is a particularily cool event, as is saturn-rise (or fall) on the inner moons. The latter really reminded me of the movie Pitch Black.

Comment: Related to: [*How will planets behave in the night sky as seen by Mars colonists?*](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/26166/how-will-planets-behave-in-the-night-sky-as-seen-by-mars-colonists)

Answer (score 26):

Yes, the free software [Stellarium](https://stellarium.org/) (also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellarium_(software))) can do that. It has a list of celestial bodies and you select which one you want to be on. When you open Stellarium go to Location Menu (or the button F6 for Windows OS) and that is where you set your viewing point.

There might be additional options in [Where can I find/visualize planets/stars/moons/etc positions?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/13488/7982)

Answer (score 15):

Another simulator allowing to travel and observe from different locations is [Celestia](https://celestia.space/).

It is not online, installation needed.

Comment: I can attest that I have used this, and it is my opinion that the constellation our Solar system is in, as viewed from the Zeta Reticuli system, looks a lot like the Starship Enterprise.

Answer (score 15):

JPL’s [Solar System Simulator](https://space.jpl.nasa.gov/) lets you select from a list of various targets as well as viewpoints.

[image: View of Saturn from Jupiter]